# How would I go about converting this time string to epoch time in ruby?

Tags: ruby, time

How would I go about converting 2012-12-13T14:43:35.371Z to epoch time?

One approach I was considering was to strip the T and Z and then try to use the DateTime library to find a way to convert to epoch. Before I go down that path, I was curious if there is a gem I could use to do this quickly. On a related note, I will be doing time calculations after I convert to epoch.

Comment: post your code here...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For example:

```
require 'date'

# as an integer:
DateTime.parse('2012-12-13T14:43:35.371Z').to_time.to_i
# or as a string:
DateTime.parse('2012-12-13T14:43:35.371Z').strftime('%s')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require "time"
Time.iso8601("2012-12-13T14:43:35.371Z").to_i
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require "date"
DateTime.parse("2012-12-13T14:43:35.371Z").strftime("%s")
```

In cases where you need more control over parse, use `strptime`, which allows you to define a string that explains the format.