# Invalid date (ArgumentError) when trying to convert to epoch time

Tags: ruby, datetime

I have a `DateTime` string in the format `24/May/2015:06:51:33`

How can I convert it to epoch time?

I tried converting it using the method mentionedin [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733108/how-would-i-go-about-converting-this-time-string-to-epoch-time-in-ruby) stackoverflow question but it seems that DateTime format is wrong. Then I tried converting my Date to another format using

```
DateTime.parse("24/May/2015:06:51:33").strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:S%%z")
```

but that doesn't seem to work as well. Any help on how to do this? Note that I don't have my date variable in the date format. So I have to convert it from a string.

**UPDATE**

By doesn't seem to work I mean that the following error is thrown:

```
/home/keshav/Desktop/a.rb:6:in `parse': invalid date (ArgumentError)
    from /home/keshav/Desktop/a.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please could you explain what you mean by "doesn't seem to work" in the question? You clearly are not converting to an epoch according to the linked question or the documentation. Do you get a bad value or an error message? Put that information into the question - use the "edit" link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your DateTime object to an epoch timestamp like so:

```
datetime = DateTime.strptime("24/May/2015:06:51:33", "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
epoch = datetime.to_time.to_i
# => 1432450293
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Worth clarifying - the OP has chained two DateTime methods in their question, and it is the *first* method, `parse` which is complaining about the invalid format. A custom parse format as you describe here, is what they needed, not to try a different value for the output format.

Comment: Thanks! It works :) 
Could you also please tell me how can I get the epoch with milliseconds?

Comment: @KeshavAgarwal if you mean converting the given value to milliseconds, you could multiply the `epoch` value above by 1000 --> `epoch_in_milliseconds = epoch * 1000`.