# Converting date to UNIX time in Logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

Is it possible to convert date from "2016-08-22T09:09:55.487Z" format to UNIX time in Logstash? I have seen the opposite operation, but nothing about it.

Comment: When you ask UNIX time, could you indicate the expected output? And do you expect a number or a string?

Comment: @baudsp, I expect a number like this: 1431607046

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you'll have to convert `"2016-08-22T09:09:55.487Z"` to a date object, with the date filter:
(supposing that the field `date` contains a string representing a valid ISO8601 timestamp)

```
date {
    match => ["date", "ISO8601"]
    target => "date_object"
}
```

At this point you'll have a field `date_object` containing a logstash timestamp. 
This timestamp can be converted to its epoch equivalent with the `to_i` method.
To do this we'll have to use the ruby filter, which allow to execute ruby code as a filter.

```
ruby {    
    code => set.event('date_epoch', event.get('date_object').to_i)"  
}
```

Then you'll have a field `date_epoch`, which will be a number representing the UNIX time.

Answer (score 2):

I came across a similar issue today. Unfortunately the peace of config above has a limitation that it *loses milliseconds* from the timestamp during the integer conversion:

> ruby {
>      code => "event['date_epoch'] = event['date_object'].to_i"
>   }

I’ve tried several options including converting the date object to float, multiplying it by 1000 and then back to string. The bottom line is that the precision was not exactly the same.

Finally I came up with this a bit *hacky* sample below. It worked with logstash version 2.4.1.
So first I create a field `tmpTimestamp` in order to convert the parsed timestamp into a plain String:

```
mutate{
add_field => ["tmpTimestamp","%{@timestamp}"]
}
```

A peace of ruby code to cast the string into a standard ruby DateTime format, convert it to the epoch format (including ms) and then back to String:

```
ruby { code => "require 'date';event['epoch'] = DateTime.parse(event['tmpTimestamp']).strftime('%Q').to_s" }
```

Remove unused tmp variable:

```
mutate{
remove_field => ["tmpTimestamp"]
}
```

Comment: Also refer to this for general Ruby date conversion to epoch:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14733261/2695332
The date input need not be the entire timestamp. It can just be the date in formats like MM/DD/YYYY or MM-DD-YYYY etc.

Comment: on version 8.6.1 event['variable'] doesnt work

ruby {
        id => "convert_timestamp"
        code => "require 'date';event.set('epoch', (DateTime.parse(event.get('tmpTimestamp')).strftime('%Q').to_s))"
    }